# Execute stored procedure from Azure datafactory

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am trying to execute a stored procedure in an Azure SQL database from an Azure DataFactory V2. The procedure will do some upsert into different tables with data from a flat table. According to [MS specifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database#invoking-stored-procedure-for-sql-sink) you need to have a table valued parameter to make such thing, but that couples the pipeline activity to the procedure and to all the models. Is there any way to define the dataset and copy activity so it just executes the stored procedure?

The jsons below are from the arm template:

```
DataSet:    
{"type": "datasets",
          "name": "AzureSQLProcedureDS",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[parameters('dataFactoryName')]",
            "[parameters('destinationLinkedServiceName')]"
          ],
          "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
          "properties": {
            "type": "AzureSqlTable",
            "linkedServiceName": {
              "referenceName": "[parameters('destinationLinkedServiceName')]",
              "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
            },
            "typeProperties": {
              "tableName": "storedProcedureExecutions"
            }
          }}




    Activity:
    {"name": "ExecuteHarmonizationProcedure",
                    "description": "Executes the procedure that Harmonizes the Data",
                    "type": "Copy",
                    "inputs": [
                      {
                        "referenceName": "[parameters('destinationDataSetName')]",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                      }
                    ],
                    "outputs": [
                      {
                        "referenceName": "AzureSQLProcedureDS",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                      }
                    ],
                    "typeProperties": {
                      "source": {
                        "type": "SqlSink"
                      },
                      "sink": {
                        "type": "SqlSink",
                        //"SqlWriterTableType": "storedProcedureExecutionsType",
                        "SqlWriterStoredProcedureName": "@Pipeline().parameters.procedureName",
                        "storedProcedureParameters": {
                          "param1": {
                            "value": "call from adf" 
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated considering that MS doesn't provide so much help for this subject.

Comment: Can you describe where you encounter a difficulty and what error message you get?

Comment: The purpose was to find something that does not make neccessary the creation of a dummy table, because in this case this is a bit more prone to sql injection. If there is a way to specify only the name of the procedure and the needed parameters, it would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the problem correctly, you just want to call a stored procedure from a copy activity?

Doing that is pretty easy, in a copy activity you can define the sqlReaderQuery property inside source. This property lets you enter a t-sql command, so you can do something like this:

```
 "typeProperties": {
        "source": {
            "type": "SqlSource",
            "sqlReaderQuery": "EXEC sp_Name; select 1 as test"
        },
 . . .
```

Copy activity always expects a result from the query, so if you only include the call to the stored procedure it doesnt  thats why I include the second part of the query.

Replace with the parameters you want to use and thats it.

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work. The activity runs for ~4min and then fails because it tries to map the result, probably of the select statement, into the source/destination.

Comment: Yes "select 1 as test" will return a single column called test with only a 1 as a value. Create a dummy dataset or change the query to meet your needs, the example I gave you is just to show how you can call a stored procedure from a copy activity..

Comment: I did as you suggested and it worked, but as I posted below it is more a workaround than a direct solution. If there is no other way, at least with current state of the DF v2, I am going to accept your answer as a solution.

Comment: Just tested those stepsto call a SP that calls the azure integration service (that you can get to run with ADFv2) and it worked!! The official documentation says that you need to call it from ADF version 1 using a stored procedure activity. This looks like a better way, given that you only use one instance of data factory.

Answer (score 1):

Following the advice of @Martin we managed to make the execution work. Below are what we did:

1. Create dummy table in SQL:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dummyTable]( [col1] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL)
   ```
2. Create a stored procedure:

   ```
   CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_testHarmonize]
        @param1 NVARCHAR(200)
   AS
   BEGIN
       INSERT INTO storedProcedureExecutions
       VALUES (@param1, GETDATE());
   END
   ```
3. Dataset for the stored procedure:

   ```
   {
       "type": "datasets",
       "name": "[parameters('dummySQLTableDataSet')]",
       "dependsOn": ["[parameters('dataFactoryName')]",
       "[parameters('datalakeLinkedServiceName')]"],
       "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
       "properties": {
               "type": "AzureSqlTable",
               "linkedServiceName": {
                   "referenceName": "[parameters('databaseLinkedServiceName')]",
                   "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
               },
       "typeProperties": {
               "tableName": "dummyTable"
       }
   }
   ```
4. Pipeline activity:

   ```
   {
       "name": "ExecuteHarmonizationProcedure",
       "dependsOn": [{
           "activity": "CopyCSV2SQL",
           "dependencyConditions": ["Succeeded"]
       }],
       "description": "Executes the procedure that Harmonizes the Data",
       "type": "Copy",
       "inputs": [{
           "referenceName": "[parameters('dummySQLTableDataSet')]",
           "type": "DatasetReference"
       }],
       "outputs": [{
           "referenceName": "[parameters('dummySQLTableDataSet')]",
           "type": "DatasetReference"
       }],
       "typeProperties": {
           "source": {
               "type": "SqlSource",
               "sqlReaderQuery": "@Pipeline().parameters.SQLCommand"
           },
           "sink": {
               "type": "SqlSink"
           }
       }
   }
   ```
5. Run the pipeline with the following parameter for the SQL command:

   ```
   $"EXEC sp_testHarmonize 'call from ADF at {DateTime.Now}'; select top 1 * from dummyTable;"
   ```

This made it worked, but it looks more as a work around than a direct solution, considering that it is inserted a row on a dummy table. If there isn't any more direct solution, this is the most easy approach.