# ADF activity is in progress state for a longer period of time

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I have a daily schedule ADF pipeline that consist of couple of activities. The first activity basically invokes a stored procedure that takes less than 2 second to run on DB side but the activity is running continuously(**In Progress state** for longer period of time). Initially I thought it was due to the blocking on SQL server side. But the problem is there is NO SQL SERVER hit from ADF side. The strange thing is running on Dev environment but getting blocked in QA.

[image]

Here is the RunId for the same:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can invoke a stored procedure with a copy activity, changing the SqlReaderQuery property to something like "exec 'sp_name'". I explained this here: [Execute storedProcedure from azure datafactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47903441/execute-storedprocedure-from-azure-datafactory/47905719#47905719)

Your problem looks like the integration runtime cannot reach the database, try opening the integration runtime, and connecting to the database from the diagnostic tab. Once you make it work there, make sure the linked service is configured with those credentials.

Hope this helped!